# "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column..." even though I'm not

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have this function:

```
private static void SaveResource(StrategicPlanningDbDataContext ctx, ResourceModel resource, int impliedID)
    {
        var existing = ctx.Resources.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ID == resource.ID) ??
                       new Resource();

        existing.ImpliedID = impliedID;
        existing.HasAccepted = resource.HasAccepted;
        existing.IsPrimary = existing.IsPrimary;
        existing.UserID = resource.UserID;

        if (existing.ID == default(int))
        {
            ctx.Resources.InsertOnSubmit(existing);
            ctx.SubmitChanges();
            resource.ID = existing.ID;
        }
    }
```

I'm getting a `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Resource' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.` message when I hit ctx.SubmitChanges() for a new `Resource`. `Resource.ID` is an Identity (obviously). It's 0 when we come into the function (because I just created it, and `int`s obviously have to have a default value.

I've tried deleting the table from my dbml and re-adding it several times, but I keep getting this error. I've checked the designer, and the designer has `[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]` above the ID property.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I closed and restarted Visual Studio and it all got better. (As an aside, it was also compiling just fine if I completely removed tables from the .dbml, which, uh, didn't make any sense).